# How to install Win 7 Pro without a disc

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, windows-10

I have bought a computer that has a sticker on it for a Win 7 Pro with a Product Key. Now I need to format that computer and install Windows 7 - I don't have previous user password. How I should do that. BTW it is preferable to install Win 10, because if I will install win 7 then I will upgrade it to Win 10.

I try to use [Recovery site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) and I get this message:

> The product key you entered appears to be for software that was
>   pre-installed on a device.

Comment: Are you locked out of computer now ? What do you mean by recovery site ?

Comment: Added a link. Yes I can't login as the user password is unknown.

Comment: "The product key you entered appears to be for software that was pre-installed on a device." because that iso of W7 is for Retail recovery only, your key is for OEM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, someone made a partial copy of the Digital River content. It’s available [here](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/). It contains most relevant Windows 7 ISOs.

If you’re curious whether these images are genuine, you can browse the [MSDN repository](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/) without logging in and compare checksums. After downloading, of course. ;)

Comment: These are original images?

Comment: Yes. Untouched straight from MSDN/Digital River.

Comment: Great. Then when I download the iso I have to use "Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool" to make a bootable USB? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery

Comment: Yes. Although I’d recommend [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) because it’s much faster and can generate UEFI-bootable USB drives.

Comment: What is the advantage of UEFI?

Comment: Some PCs can boot (much) faster with an UEFI-based installation of newer Windows versions. If you’re planning to upgrade to Windows 10, you should definitely use it.

Comment: @DanielB  which of these 3 options do you suggest / not suggest, and why? http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/tutorials/58372d1424622042-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows-rufus.png

Comment: Depends on your machine, really. I don’t know if it can do UEFI, although it’s likely. Anyway, this is pretty far off-topic, so I suggest you ask a new question stating you plan to upgrade to Windows 10 and whatnot. Don’t forget to include the notebook or motherboard make and model!

Comment: I doubt that hardware has UEFI firmware.

Answer (score -2):

If it was pre-installed on your device (e.g. a laptop) then you can assume you need to buy another product key. OEM product keys are single use (Weird, I know) which I'm assuming is so that some OEM doesn't make a million laptops with a single key. So basically, your sticker is useless. You might as well buy Windows 7 Pro off Amazon, and get a disk, and a multi-use key out of that purchase. Sorry man, but you're screwed if you really have to wipe the disk.

Comment: This seems like a comment.  Given you can download Windows 7 without a key, I am not sure, I entirely agree with your comment either.

Comment: More likely that the OP has an OEM installation and needs the OEM DVD/iso. That way it will automatically activate.  Or the OP needs to use the key **and a matching installation medium**, which is **not** the OEM version.

Comment: Not true - I've done a few installs using the sticker key and retail-oem media